# xcode6でiOS8シュミレータで英語のUIしか表示されない

Tags: ios, xcode6

xcode5でiOS7用アプリを作り、UIはストーリーボードで英語と日本語を作りました。

en.lproj
　MainStoryboard_iPhone.storyboard
ja.lproj
　MainStoryboard_iPhone.storyboard

そのアプリをiOS8に対応させることにしました。

xcodeを6にアップデートしました。
とりあえずビルドしてiOS8シュミレータで起動すると、設定で言語を日本語にしても英語版のUIしか表示されません。
なにか設定が足りないのでしょうか？

シュミレータをiOS7にすれば正しくOSの設定の言語を切り替えればUIも切り替わります。

このアプリは私が作成した物ではなく、他の人が作ったiOS7用アプリを急にメンテすることを任されたのでxcodeの使い方やアプリの作成方法などのノウハウが私にはありません。
もしかしたら基本的な質問かもしれませんが、こちらで質問させていただくことにしました。
iOS開発にお詳しい方がいましたらよろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

スキーマの設定にLanguageとRegionというのが増えていて、その設定が使用されるようになっています。
「Edit Scheme...」からスキーマの編集画面に行き、「Language」を「Japanese」、必要に応じて「Region」も「日本」に設定すると、日本語のUIで使用できます。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: キャプチャまで取っていただいて非常に助かりました。
ありがとうございます。
教えていただいた設定で正しく表示されました。
ただし、IPhone6のシュミレータはまだ言語環境が不安定らしく、一部正しく動きませんでした。
実機では上記の方法で問題なく動作いたしました。